# How to get geolocation in .netcore 2 c#

Tags: c#, geolocation, asp.net-core-2.0

Does anyone know how I can get GeoLocation of my browser in .net core 2 using C#? I have written an ASP site and I want to get the current location lat and long but I cant do it. I want to be able to use the lat and long found later on in my code. Any hints would be great as I am lost. Im hoping that if my browser happens to be being used on a mobile, that it will know its location based on GPS etc

Comment: As far as I know, this is only possible using javascript. So what you could do is request the user location using javascript and send it to the server using an ajax request.

Comment: This has nothing to do with .Net Core, it can only be done in the browser. There's plenty of questions on how to do that.

Comment: Look at the string response which should have "Latitude" and Longitude" values.  Without seeing the exact structure of the I can't give a good answer.  I usually use GetElementsByTagName();

Comment: you can get the ip adress from the httpcontext, but you then need to locate it, most commonly by some paid service if you can't find a free lookup. Not that the ip adress is very reliable.

Comment: @Jerodev has got your answer: use the javascript geolocation API to get the data within the browser. You would also need a server side component to receive that information. That server-side item could be in C# if you desired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant access this directly from C#. But you can get this with a javascript and submit to your server, to get on C#:

```html
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(positionSuccess, positionError)

function positionSuccess (geo) { 
  document.cookie = 'latitude=' + geo.coords.latitude;
  document.cookie = 'longitude=' + geo.coords.longitude;
  document.cookie = 'accuracy=' + geo.coords.accuracy;
}

function positionError (geo) { 
  document.cookie = 'latitude=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
  document.cookie = 'longitude=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
  document.cookie = 'accuracy=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC;';
}
```

Now, you can get it in the cookies of your request.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies. I am trying this...it is asking for permission to get location so Im pretty sure that parts working..here is what I have done. I have added @RenderSection("LocationScript", false/*required*/) to the end of my <head> section in _layout, then in the view (create.cshtml)
@section LocationScript
{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/GetLocation.js")"></script>
}
I have then create the script in that file as above.
then in my controller

Comment: [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,FlightName,FlightDate,FlightHours,Location")] FlightData flightData)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                flightData.UserId = HttpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                _context.Add(flightData);
                var latitude = Request.Cookies["latitude"];
latitude comes back as undefined...

Comment: Ops, my fault. I forgot the 'coords' in callback parameter. Update your script like the new one in my answer.

Comment: you sir are a life saver!!!! Thanks soooo much...toys were starting to get thrown out of my pram. phew...a whole day!

Comment: Any .NET Core/Standard library to use for GeoLocation data?